# iPhone froze during a software update

Tags: iphone, mac, software-update, performance

I plugged my iphone to my mac to update ios to 14.6. During the update when my mac was "preparing the iphone for the update", the wire came unplugged, after which the mac said there was a problem updating the device. I plugged it back it and the laptop is not recognizing the phone anymore. The phone is stuck at the apple logo with a 0% progress bar. Any way to fix this?

Details: iPhone 8
Macbook air 2020

i was upgrading from ios 14.4 to ios 14.6

Comment: Hi and welcome to the community! Please make sure you use the search function before opening new questions, also make sure you give as many details as possible (in this case, it would be good to know which iPhone model you are using, since the button-press combinations for restore mode vary).

Long story short: You'll need to put your iPhone in Restore Mode and then Restore it using your computer (the iPhone will be reset to factory settings so you'll need to restore your data from a backup on your computer or iCloud). Here's an Apple support article: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201263